# ASCII Code for Uppercase/Capital R with a Tilde Character Above

Tags: ascii, stata

I am trying to get the equivalent of LaTeX's $\tilde R$ in a Stata graph axis label. I don't thinks there's a SMCL way of doing that, but it's possible to use ASCII characters. However, there does not seem to be an ASCII code for an uppercase/capital R with a tilde above it.

Is there any way around that? Is it possible to combine ASCII characters somehow?

Comment: Did you figure out how to insert a tilde above a character?

Comment: @Olga See the answer below.

Comment: Yeah, I read it, tried it, but I think it's a bit beyond my Stata knowledge. Anyway, I had to use an image editing app to insert a tilde.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Stata 14, this can be accomplished with:

```
`=ustrunescape("\u0052\u0303")'
```

This combines the Unicode for capital R with the one for tilde.

---

MVE:

```
sysuse auto, clear
tw scatter price mpg, title(`=ustrunescape("\u0052\u0303")')
```

should produce something like this (modulo scheme):

[image]

Comment: dimitriy, can you say a bit more? For example, `di ustrunescape("\u0052\u0303")` displays the output `R~` (i.e. two consecutive characters, uncombined) on Stata 14.2 macOS, and Stata 17.0 on Windows 10, while ` di \`=ustrunescape("\u0052\u0303")'` displays `R~ not found`. Got a hot tip? If I copy the output from Stata output to another unicode-aware platform the combination is preserved: `R̃ not found` <—copied and pasted from Stata.

Comment: @Alexis `display` won't work for complicated reasons, but try doing it in a graph title like in my edit.

Comment: Thank you so much! As it so happens my use need is in a graph (display was just practicing). [Tries it] … Huh. For some reason glyphs resulting from combining diacritics in graph show up as a different font than non-combined unicode glyphs... another puzzle to solve.

Comment: Huh that font-changing bit seems to be a fall-back from an incomplete unicode glyph set of the font I was using. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: From Stata 14. Stata supports Unicode.

ORIGINAL ANSWER for versions up to Stata 13:

The user-written program `asciiplot` (SSC) displays those characters available to you via `char()`, depending on what alphabet you are using. Your mileage may differ, but I see no such character.

Stata does not, at this writing, support LaTeX or over-striking or combinations of ASCII characters.

Comment: This seems unfortunate given how common hats, tildes, and vinculi/macrons/overbars/overlines are in our notation. Interestingly, the [beta hat](http://www.stata.com/giftshop/beta-hat/) sold in the Stata gift store also lacks a hat.

Comment: I expect, or more precisely hope, that LaTeX support is on the agenda for StataCorp.